# PHP / Apache sh error permission denied on every request

Tags: php, linux, apache

I've got a recently setup server which is running Apache and PHP 5.3.9, every request made to the server results in an error in the error log file:

```
sh: line 0: cd: /root: Permission denied
```

The error is happening before any PHP code is executed so it must be something in the setup somewhere but it's a new box and is running a stock configuration.

What would cause this error?

EDIT:

Running on Amazon Linux (EC2) 2.6.35.14-97.44.amzn1.x86_64

It shouldn't be running any scripts, it's running PHP in mod_php mode, not CGI and the error is happening before and PHP code is executed

Comment: What system are you running? What versions? Give us more info :)

Comment: Same problem here on an Amazon instance. I'm not running any script whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

Could look like a script that does not have executable rights.

If you know which script it is, you can give it the rights by:

```
chmod +x /path/to/your/script.sh
```

As root or with sudo infront.

Edit:

Looking agin, it looks like your script is trying to cd to your /root folder.
Most likely the script is run by another user which does not have permission to cd to /root.
Only root has that

Comment: The error is happening before any of my scripts are run and even happens on a page with no PHP code at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is the AWSSDKforPHP doing this.

Inside `/usr/share/pear/AWSSDKforPHP/sdk.class.php` you will find:

```
$_ENV['HOME'] = `cd ~ && pwd`;
```

For some silly reason, it's trying to "cd" into `/root`. Change that line to the following:

```
$_ENV['HOME'] = "/var/www"; #`cd ~ && pwd`;
```

And it will go away.